# Is there any way to use python function in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script

If I have a python script, for example:

```
def hello():
    return 'Hello World'
```

How can I call this python script in Google App Script? Or how can I create a custom function for spreadsheet which return this python function?
Something like:

```
function callPythonFunction() {
  const result = //hello function from python script
  return result; // 'Hello World' from hello()
}
```

And if I use this in spreadsheet:

```
=callPythonFunction()
```

I get 'Hello World' in the cell.

Comment: You might be able to do this using an alternate runtime. This feature is probably still in beta but you can check it out at the following link: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no another way other than running the python app in a 3rd party service and then call it from GAS using `UrlFetch()` (I've seen someone do this but not tried it entirely), or using Google's [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api) in python or [`gspread`](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html) if you want to have access onto spreadsheets.